# Extract a percentage of columns meeting filter R

Tags: r

I have a df as such:

```
df <- data.frame(genename = c("A","B","C","D"),
             sample1 = c(10,0,50,0), 
             sample2 = c(0,30,0,70), 
             sample3 = c(50,0,0,30), 
             sample4 = c(0,0,0,10))
```

I want to extract the rows with at least 50% columns having >0
e.g. for df genename A and D meet the requirement

I have worked this out for all columns

```
df2<-as.data.frame(df[apply(df ,MARGIN=1, function(x) all(x>0)),])
```

but I can't work this out for a percentgae of the columns meeting the requirement???

Comment: But the row where `genename == "A"` has only *one* entry `>0`, so only 25% of the entries fulfil `>0`. Why does `A` pass your condition? And conversely, why do `B` and `C` *not* pass your condition?

Comment: Apologies, I have made an edit so the df is now correct

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Solution using base R:

```
df[apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) sum(x > 0) / length(x)) > 0.5, ]
#  genename sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
#1        A      10       0      50      70
#4        D       0      70      30      10
```

Explanation: Filter rows based on the percentage of `>0` entries being `>50%` across all columns except the first.

### Method 2

Solution using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% mutate(frac = rowSums(.[-1] > 0) / length(.[-1])) %>% filter(frac > 0.5)
#  genename sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 frac
#1        A      10       0      50      70 0.75
#4        D       0      70      30      10 0.75
```

Comment: Interesting that this is identical to my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49483834/1504321).

Comment: @ctbrown indeed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general solution:

```
df <- data.frame(genename = c("A","B","C","D"),               
            sample1 = c(0,10,0,0), sample2 = c(10,30,50,0), sample3=c(0,40,50,10), sample4=c(0,40,0,10))

df[(rowSums(df[-1]>0))>= (ncol(df[-1])/2),]
#   genename sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
# 2        B      10      30      40      40
# 3        C       0      50      50       0
# 4        D       0       0      10      10
```

This will work for any data frame where the first colum is your gene name, and you want 50% or more of the other columns to have nonzero values.

The logic of this is as follows:

Take the data frame from the second column onward: `df[-1]`, and turn it into a logical dataframe with `TRUE` where there is a value greater than 0: `df[-1]>0`.  Then find out how many columns have `TRUE` in each row: `rowSums(df[-1]>0)`.  This returns a vector of length `nrow(df)`, with values equal to the number of nonzero values in each column of the corresponding row of `df`.  Use that to generate a logical vector of those rows with at least half of the sample values greater than 0: `rowSums(df[-1]>0) >= ncol(df[-1])/2`, and subset `df` by rows to get those rows that make the expression `TRUE`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `ncol` instead of `nrow`?

Comment: yes. fixed. Thanks! Note that the result is the same, because of the structure of the example. But yes, for it to be a general solution and to make sense, you're absolutely correct, we need it to be `nrow`.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df[ 
  apply( df[, -1], 1, function(x) sum(x>0)/length(x) > 0.5 ) , 
]

      genename sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
1        A      10       0      50      70
4        D       0      70      30      10
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this seems to be identical to [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49483768/6530970) I posted earlier.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I agree. There looks to be just a trivial shift of `)` from your answer

Comment: We were apparently working on the same solution at the same time.  Interesting,  but not surprising, o see that we came up with the same solution.